# Плавно анимировать появление элемента

Tags: javascript

Вроде бы при подобном коде всё должно изменяться плавно, но подобного, к сожалению, не происходит.

```js
let button = document.createElement('button');
button.style.opacity = 0;
document.body.append(button);
button.style.opacity = 1;
```

```css
button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 1s;
  }
```

Comment: @Eugene Novikov  ваш код document.body.append(button);  а надо наверное document.body.appendChild(button);

Comment: @Leks https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: @Stranger in the Q сейчас ознакомлюсь

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  спасибо за ликбез

Comment: @Leks нет проблем, лишь бы в радость, вы написали грустный комментарий под своим постом, но это не мешает Вам дополнить свой ответ, чтобы он был корректен и получить плюсик =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо позволить браузеру отрендерить первое состояние чтобы он решил сделать `transition` во второе

В вашем случае браузер рендерит сразу  `opacity = 1`, т.к. вызовы идут один за одним и по факту "доходит" до рендеринга только последнее состояние установленное в одной цепочке вызовов

Вызов

```
setTimeout(() => button.style.opacity = 1)
```

откладывает выполнение `opacity = 1` и браузер сначала рендерит `opacity = 0` а потом уже понимает что надо бы сделать `transition`

```js
let button = document.createElement('button');
button.style.opacity = 0;
document.body.append(button);
setTimeout(() => button.style.opacity = 1)
```

```css
button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 1s;
  }
```

Или необходимо использовать `@keyframes`

```js
let button = document.createElement('button');
document.body.append(button);
```

```css
button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  animation: show 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes show{
  0%   { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'text';
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

```css
button{
 background-color: red;
 transition: 0s;
}
button:hover{
 background-color: blue;
 transition: .6s;
 color: #fff;
}
```

P.S я заметил Вы забыли добавить Child к append

Comment: *Вопрос был в том, чтобы кнопка добавлялась изначально невидимой и плавно становилась видимой... а не про наведение.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME  сейчас исправлю (попытаюсь)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME про keyframes уже написали :((